# How to use right, reselect in react-redux aplication

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where user can search data depending by his input. In my application i try to use reselect.

```js
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { searchPersonAction } from "./store";

    const Search = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const selector = useSelector((s) => s);
      const search = (e) => {
        const txt = e.target.value;
        dispatch(searchPersonAction(txt));
      };
      return (
        <div>
          <input onChange={search} placeholder="search" />
          <ul>
            {selector.name.map((p) => (
              <li key={p.name}>{p.name}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default Search;
```

In my `store` i have an array of persons like this:

```js
    export const persons = [
        {
            name:"jack",
            age: 2
        },
        {
            name:"Jim",
            age: 14
        },
        {
            name:"July",
            age: 92
        },
        {
            name:"Bill",
            age: 1
        },
        {
            name:"Carl",
            age: 72
        },
    ]
```

Now, when user search something, in the list appears the results according to the name which was searched by the user.
**Question: Is  the reselect usefull (protects from to many re-renders) in my case or not? Or using `useSelector`, in the case above is enought?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think reslect here will be necessary. You can use `useMemo` to achieve the same result.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { searchPersonAction } from "./store";

    const Search = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const persons = useSelector((s) => s.persons);

      const [query, updateQuery] = useState('');
      const searchedPersons = useMemo(() => persons.filter(p => p.name.includes(query)), [query]);

      const search = (e) => {
        updateQuery(e.target.value);
      };
      return (
        <div>
          <input onChange={search} placeholder="search" />
          <ul>
            {searchedPersons.map((p) => (
              <li key={p.name}>{p.name}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

`reselect` will be useful if you get `array` or `object` from `store` for example:

**store**

```
state = {
    persons: [
        {
            name:"Jack",
            age: 2
        },
        {
            name:"Jane",
            age: 14
        },
    ]
}
```

if you used `selector` from `react-redux` and if your typed `'J'` in the search field and used `searchPersonAction` action, then it will change the array of `persons` in the `store`, but array stayed the same.

```
state = {
    persons: [
        {
            name:"Jack",
            age: 2
        },
        {
            name:"Jane",
            age: 14
        },
    ]
}
```

then you receive rerender regardless of whether the data in the array has changed or not.

But if you use `reselect` and when your typed `'Ja'` in the search field, it will be the same array, then you will not get a repeated render, because `reselect` will memoize data